# Как работает и что внутри файла __init__.py в проектах на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, init

Почти всегда в директории с каким либо python проектом вижу файл `__init__.py`, но не могу полностью понять зачем он нужен и как он устроен. Примеров с его содержимым много, но как он работает не понятно

Answer (score 1):

Файл `__init__.py` показывает интерпретатору, что данный каталог следует воспринимать как пакет.